# Can't read serial data from /dev/ttyUSB0

Tags: usb, hardware, serial-port

I am using an RS485 to USB adapter in order to communicate with hardware, whose parameters can be changed by sending data strings in hex. I set:

```
sudo chmod o+rw /dev/ttyUSB0
stty -F /dev/ttyUSB0 19200 -parodd
```

Two terminals are open. The first is:

```
cat -v < /dev/ttyUSB0
```

The second being:

```
echo -e "\x00\x00\x00\x10\x96\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x92" < /dev/ttyUSB0
```

The device should send back a similar string, but I receive nothing in the first terminal. The data string being sent has been verified as the correct format by the manufacturer. Why is there no response?

edit: Just to provide some more info on this, I have also attempted in terminal 1 `hexdump < /dev/ttyUSB0` to no avail. I have also toggled each of the following `stty` settings on/off to determine if they had any effect:

```
parenb, ixon, crtscts, cread
```

This is currently what running `stty -a < /dev/ttyUSB0` looks like:

```
speed 19200 baud; rows 0; columns 0; line = 0;
intr = ^C; quit = ^\; erase = ^?; kill = ^U; eof = ^D; eol = <undef>; eol2 = <undef>;
swtch = <undef>; start = ^Q; stop = ^S; susp = ^Z; rprnt = ^R; werase = ^W; lnext = ^V; discard = ^O;
min = 1; time = 0;
parenb -parodd -cmspar cs8 hypcl -cstopb cread clocal crtscts
-ignbrk -brkint -ignpar -parmrk -inpck -istrip -inclr -igncr -icrnl ixon -ixoff -iuclc -ixany
-ixmabel -iutf8
-opost -olcuc -ocrnl onlcr -onocr -onlret -ofill -ofdel nl0 cr0 tab0 bs0 vt0 ff0
-isig -icanon iexten -echo echoe echok -echonl -noflsh -xcase -tostop -echoprt echoctl echoke -flusho
-extproc
```

Comment: are you sure your device is using even parity for error checking?

Comment: @fcbsd I am fairly sure. I've attempted it with other parity settings (odd, even, none, and mark) but still was unable to get a response.

Comment: okay - it's times like this when I use a bus pirate to debug issues...sorry that doesn't help you now...

Comment: @fcbsd I was unaware of the pirate bus before this, I'll definitely give it a try. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have mixed up `<` with `>`. You have

```
echo -e ... < /dev/ttyUSB0
```

but it must be

```
echo -e ... > /dev/ttyUSB0
```

Comment: I've attempted your fix and unfortunately still receive nothing back in the first terminal.

Comment: It seems there were some previously unknown driver and device issues which I have found since posting this question. I've marked this as correct now, since if these issues had been solved at the time of posting the question, this answer would be the correct solution.